# what is the relationship between joint and marginal probability of dependent random variables?

Tags: probability-theory

If $x$ and $(y_1,y_2)$ are independent random variables, then we know that $$f(x,y_1,y_2)=f(x)f(y_1,y_2)$$
now if they are not independent is it true that $$f(x,y_1,y_2) < f(x)f(y_1,y_2)$$ or not?

Answer (score 1):

No. If $f(x,y) < f(x) f(y)$ for all $x,y$, then integrating over $y$ we'd get $f(x)<f(x)$